# Passing an Array Argument in a GET request in mulesoft

Tags: api, mule, postman, mulesoft

I am passing an array in an API as an argument to a get request. I new to pass this array as a query parameter to an HTTP Requester.

I am using flow variable for string and numbers. But I don't know what to use for Arrays.

I saw some examples using the foreach scope and tried that but I was told that I can not use foreach in http:request-builder. Please is there a work around this? I am new in Mulesoft. Thanks

**illustration**

https://apiEndPoint/api/Get?param1=Americas&param2=00MA&param3=Disruption&param3=SomethingElse

param1 and param2 are captured with flow variables and sent with the HTTP Requester

Using flow variable for param3 overwrites Disruption with Something else

```
<http:request-builder>
                <http:query-param paramName="param1" value="#[flowVars.param1]" />
                <http:query-param paramName="param2" value="#[flowVars.param2]" />
                <http:query-param paramName="param3"value="#[flowVars.param3]" />

</http:request-builder>
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to create a map from the list, with keys 'param1', 'param2', etc. The HTTP request builder allows to use a map to generate all the query params, using the keys as the names. To create the map I used DataWeave:

```
    <flow name="test-array-query-paramFlow">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/test" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <set-variable variableName="myArray" value="#[ [ 'Americas','00MA', 'Disruption', 'SomethingElse' ] ]" doc:name="Variable"/>
        <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
            <dw:set-variable variableName="params"><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
( flowVars.myArray map {
  ("param" ++ ($$ as :number +1)) : $
} )  reduce ((val, acc = {}) -> acc ++ val)
]]></dw:set-variable>
        </dw:transform-message>
        <logger message="payload #[flowVars.params]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="/api" method="GET" doc:name="HTTP">
            <http:request-builder>
                <http:query-params expression="#[flowVars.params]"/>
            </http:request-builder>
        </http:request>
</flow>
```

Enabling [HTTP wire logging](https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/How-to-Enable-HTTP-Wire-Logging) we can confirm the params are generated as expected:

```
GET /api?param1=Americas&param2=00MA&param3=Disruption&param4=SomethingElse HTTP/1.1
```

Answer (score 0):

When setting up the http requester, I added query parameters and this expression

#[message.inboundProperties['http.query.params']]

And it fixed the issue for me. I didn't have to set the variables again.

```
<http:request-builder>
            <http:query-params
                expression="#[message.inboundProperties['http.query.params']]" />


        </http:request-builder>
```